# Why do I get a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when editing a list of lists?

Tags: java

Here is something I can't really figure out: I'm programming a card game to check how many hands are needed to finish it. The problem is that I'm getting a really weird `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Here is what happens: I have modelled a Deck as a list of Cards. I loop over all the Decks and always remove the top card.

(in the code below "players" is a list of decks. I have created this list by splitting the deck in two using the split function i've made in the 'Deck' class)

```
public static Deck oneHand(List<Deck> players){

    List<Card> hand = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
           hand.add(players.get(i).pop()); //The exception seems to be thrown the second time here
    }

    //The hand is being played here
}
```

Here is the deck function. The decks gets initiated in the constructors.

```
public class Deck{

    private List<Card> cards

    public Deck() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cards.add(new Card(i, Suit.values()[j])); //nice and unique
        }
    }

    Collections.shuffle(cards);
    }

    public Deck(List<Card> cards) {
        this.cards = cards;
    }

    public List<Deck> split(int n){
    if(n > cards.size()){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can only split in max " + cards.size() + " elements.");
    }

    List<Deck> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int part = (int) Math.ceil(cards.size()/n);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        result.add(new Deck(cards.subList((i-1)*part, Math.min(i*part, cards.size()))));
    }

    return result;
    }


    public Card pop(){
         return cards.remove(0);
    }
}
```

The `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown on the cards.remove, but why? I'm not looping over the cards, am I? And I'm not removing Decks?

If it helps: I have debugged and noticed that exception is thrown at the second player (but, strangely, not the first), which is also the last player. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using an iterator instead of a for loop?

Comment: The issue is not obvious from the code you've provided. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @Lorelorelore A `ConcurrentModificationException` usually comes from the use of an `Iterator`, so I guess the answer is probably yes.

Comment: Are you sure? I don’t think `ArrayList.remove` can throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Or maybe you mean that the removal of a card causes the exception elsewhere? That’s likely,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We’d love to help. We can by all likely do that if you provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the data used, the expected result and the full stack trace from your exception and tell us which line in your code the stack trace refers to. So please…

Comment: thanks for the help guys! I've edited in more detail, hope it helps! (I'm new here you see)

Comment: I have tried with an iterator, but the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

From your code, and without the Player implementation, I am under the impression you are sharing sublist for each player.

- The sublist *may* simply be a view to its owner list.
- Removing stuff on a sublist *may* change the view.
- Removing stuff on a sublist based on same view *may* throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` because the first time you invalidated the view for the other sublist.

Let's say that you have a List(A, B, C, D):

- L1 = sublist(0, 2) returns [A, B] but it may be implemented as a view whose `startIndex` is 0 and `endIndex` is 2. Because the index may be invalidated the implementation remembers the last "state" of the view.
- L2 = sublist(2, 4) returns [C, D] but it may be implemented as a view whose `startIndex` is 2 and `endIndex` is 4. Because the index may be invalidated the implementation remembers the last "state" of the view.
- `L1.remove(index)` means `view.remove(startIndex + index)`. It works: the view state is now changed.
- `L2.remove(index)` means `view.remove(startIndex + index)`. It fails: the view state mismatch the sublist.

**TL;DR:** you should copy the sublist in your Player instantiation.

Comment: That did it! thanks! I had no idea sublist didn't copy